# How do I send a message from python to C++

Tags: python, c++, binding, swig, openframeworks

I'm trying to get an example of openFramworks (C++) and python to work together, thus far, following an example I've been able to call python fucntion from C++ in the follwoing manner

```
ofxPythonObject klass = python.getObject("myApp");
if(klass)
    python_program = klass();
python_program.method("subscribe");
```

The interface uses swig under the hood, I'm wondering how do I send a message back to C++ from python, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible through SWIG, but you could use a PUB\SUB from python to C. Might be overkill and just a suggestion, and one that I would have left in your comments had my score been adequate.

```
#publish in Python
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# receive in C
include <zmq.hpp>
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
```

Good luck.